# Integration of webix tables and backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, webix

I am tying to integrate webix tables with a backbone collection as shown in the webix docs (http://docs.webix.com/desktop__backbone_collections.html) however it does not seem to work. The object sync call happens, but no data is loaded.

```
   budgets = new Backbone.Budget.Collection(window.budget)
   list =
        width               : 320
        view                : "datatable"
        id                  : "budget_list"
        backbone_collection : budgets
        select              : true
        scroll              : false
        columns             :[
                {header : "Month",             id: "budget_month"}
                {header : "Year",              id: "budget_year"}
                {header : "Currency",          id: "base_currency"}
                ]

        on: {
                onAfterRender       :  () ->
                        console.log("Sync ", @_settings)
                        @sync(@_settings.backbone_collection)

                }
```

Comment: Can you post `Backbone.Budget.Collection` and structure of `window.budget` ?

Comment: @ZacharyK Could you post you model code ? and where you set the url to the REST service

Answer (score 2):

Calling .sync from the onAfterRender causes the problem, as sync causes re-rendering of datatable, which triggers new sync and it causes new re-rendering and etc.

To break this loop you can use webix.once which will guarantee that handler will be executed only once.

Check the updated snippet http://webix.com/snippet/5dd61a47

Answer (score 1):

Its very possible that the server you are hitting 1) is not specifying `'Content-type: application/json'` and this is rejected by the client on the response; and, or 2) doesn't response to the OPTIONS pre-flight thus throws up a [CORS security block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). Both are difficult to solve without access to the server.

Curl will not be subject to the CORS issue but a browser-based REST client will -- and thus best represent your issue.

Try using the [Chrome advanced rest client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) with the URL and headers given in the UI.

And if you dont know the URL and header then [sniff your requests](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-sniffer/ndfgffclcpdbgghfgkmooklaendohaef) when you run that UI.

Comment: there are no cors issues its all on the same server, and yes, the server is sending a content type (webmachine tends to get HTTP very correct)